# How can I simulate a small reoccurring, overlapping location path in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

When you're debugging in simulator on OS X, you can choose to simulate your location when using MapView, etc. They have some basic routes to use.

But for what I'm trying to do, I need a recurring, overlapping path which isn't very long, maybe 500-1000m.

Does anyone know how I can simulate this in Xcode without having to go outside and run laps around a block? lol

Comment: Can you fake input data, e.g. generate it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've figured out a bit of a hack instead, because I'm not even sure you can do this. But this works for my needs.

Incase anyone else needs to do this, all I did was picked **Freeway Drive** from **Debug -> Location** and then let it run, and then just picked it again so it would start all over. This helped me simulate an overlapping path in a sense.